# xamarin run test individually

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have created an Xamarin Android project and one PCL and one Shared Library. 
I added some business logic into Shared Library and I would like to test those classes through Xamarin Studio. Those items are not related with UI so I do not need to launch emulator.

[image]

Is there any way for me to select & run tests individually?

Comment: I haven't used Xamarin Studio a lot but can you right click on the test and select Debug Test (or something along these lines)?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no option like that as VS does.

Comment: What testing framework are you using? What sort of project are those tests in? The tests should appear. If you create a NUnit library project do the tests appear after you build the project?

Comment: @MattWard I created though Solution -> New Project -> Android -> Tests -> Unit Test App (Creates an Android Uni Tests Project) and apparently it is using NUnit.Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Taken from my answer on the Xamarin Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61411/xamarin-run-test-individually):

The tests should appear in the Unit Tests pad if you are using NUnit. If I create an NUnit Library project in Xamarin Studio and build the project I can see the tests.

The screenshot is showing an Android Unit Test library project. The Android Unit Test library is using a special version of NUnit. This project type has to be run with an Android device or simulator. There is no integration into the Xamarin Studio Unit Tests window for this type of project. If you set the Android Unit Test Library project as the startup project you can run the emulator and then run the tests from inside the Android emulator. If you look in the MainActivity file you will see that the code adds the tests from the entire assembly for that project.

If you want to write tests for code that is not Android specific then create an NUnit library project and then reference your PCL or Shared project. The NUnit Library project will have full integration with the Unit Tests window allowing you to run and debug individual tests.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your test project is built, tests should show up there. The only time my UnitTest pad is blank is if I have cleaned recently and not built my tests projects.